# Sorting Map<ArrayList, List<Entity>> by Key - ArrayList is set of Dates

Tags: java, collections, comparator, sortedmap

Below is code for the Comparator, however after SortedMap.putAll(), the SortedMap has lesser number of Map Entries as compared to the source Map.

Could anyone please help?

```
Comparator<ArrayList> arrayListComparer = new Comparator<ArrayList>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(ArrayList arrA, ArrayList arrB) {
                    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-yyyy");
                    Date dateA = new Date();
                    Date dateB = new Date();
                    try {
                        dateA = formatter.parse(arrA.get(0).toString());
                        dateB = formatter.parse(arrB.get(0).toString());
                    } catch (ParseException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(ValueComparator.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                    if (dateA.before(dateB)) {
                        return 0;
                    } else if (dateA.after(dateB)) {
                        return 1;
                    } else {
                        return -1;
                    }
                }
            };
SortedMap sorted_map = new TreeMap(arrayListComparer);
sorted_map.putAll(map);
```

Comment: no exceptions when you run this?

Comment: Whatever your logic of comparator, that should never happen. You are probably looking at a wrong thing.

Comment: can you give the data set you are testing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're using `SortedMap` or `SortedSet` your `Comparator` should return 0 only if two objects are equals. Because it treats key equality by this criteria.

See natural ordering: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

> For example, if one adds two keys a and b such that (!a.equals(b) &&
>   a.compareTo(b) == 0) to a sorted set that does not use an explicit
>   comparator, the second add operation returns false (and the size of
>   the sorted set does not increase) because a and b are equivalent from
>   the sorted set's perspective.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you could show us an example of your Map, but I'll risk an answer anyway.

What's probably causing this is that you have entries in your Map to which your `compare` method (in your comparator), returns 0, this means the keys are equal. If they are equal, then it's the same key... and you can't have duplicate keys in a Map.

Can you see the problem?

I'll put a little example on:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Bla, String> map = new HashMap<Bla, String>();
    map.put(new Bla(1,1), "bla1");
    map.put(new Bla(1,2), "bla2");
    map.put(new Bla(1,3), "bla3");

    System.out.println(map.size());

    TreeMap<Bla, String> treeMap = new TreeMap<Bla,String>(new Comparator<Bla>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Bla bla, Bla bla1) {
            return new Integer(bla.a).compareTo(bla1.a);
        }
    });

    treeMap.putAll(map);

    System.out.println(treeMap.size());

}

private static class Bla{

    private Bla(int a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public int a;
    public int b;
}
```

This will output

3
1

Because my comparator says that all three keys are the same (only comparing the "a" value).

Comment: Hi, it was just the issue of equality. :) Thank you so much for trying to help though. My bad, trying to code all night ;)